# Time complexity for inner for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, time, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have a question about time complexity of the following program below. I know why the first for loop is n + 2 but for the second for loop why is it (n+1)/2?

// sample for loop 
// this is not a fully coded program just for loop time complexity analysis

```
for (int i=n; i>=0; i--) //n + 2
    for (int j=i; j<n; j++) // (n+2)(n+1)/2
        cout << i << “,” << j <<endl; //(n+1)(n)/2
```

Comment: You code was cut off, perhaps during copying and pasting. Could you please edit the question to show the code?

Comment: Your inner loop, taken separately, will always be O(n). And note that `n` in O(n) is *not* the same as your variable `n`, it's just the standard name for any variable number.

Comment: Wait...how is that n+2 and (n+1)/2? I literally don't know how to answer the question.

Comment: your code won't compile due to the stupid smart quotes

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73990/rotate-image-90-degree-clockwise/74022#74022 for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop runs `n-i` times; i.e it runs 0 times when `i==n`, then  1 time when `i == n-1`, etc, up to `n` times when `i == 0` ;  for a total of `n*(n+1)/2` times. (not `(n+1)*(n+2)/2` as stated in your comments).

Since the inner loop is initiated `n+1` times (not `n+2`, as you state), it's fair to say that the *average* number of times it runs is `n/2`.

Answer (score 2):

First your first loop has time complexity of O(n) and nested loop normal has a time complexity of O(n^2), but the inner loop is executed i times, for each value of i. The outer loop is executed n times, thus you see a pattern of execution like this: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n times

Specific Info:

1. O(1): Time complexity of a function (or set of statements) is
   considered as O(1) if it doesn’t contain loop, recursion and call to
   any other non-constant time function.
2. O(n): Time Complexity of a
   loop is considered as O(n) if the loop variables is incremented /
   decremented by a constant amount. For example following functions
   have O(n) time complexity.
3. O(n^c): Time complexity of nested loops is equal to the number of times the innermost   statement is executed.

Source - > [Link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/)

Comment: Please correct me if I got anything wrong and comment if you feel like I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating `i` from 1 to `N`, and `j` from 1 to the current value of `i` inclusive, is like exploring one half of a rectangle of dimensions `N` by `N+1`, split diagonally. To appreciate this, draw out the table for yourself on paper:  `i` on the rows, `j` on the columns, and a tick in each cell that the nested loop visits.

Comment: This is a nice analogy.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the `for` loop is O(N^2).

I just answered a similar question on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74022/37893).

Here's a simple program that illustrates the time complexity of the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int N = 10;

   int numTotalOps = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   {
      size_t numOps = 0;
      for (int j=i; j < N; j++)
      {
         cout << i << "," << j << endl;
         ++numTotalOps;
         ++numOps;
      }
      cout << "\nNumber of operations for i = " << i << ": " << numOps << endl;
   }

   cout << "\nNumber of total operations: " << numTotalOps << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
0,5
0,6
0,7
0,8
0,9

Number of operations for i = 0: 10
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8
1,9

Number of operations for i = 1: 9
2,2
2,3
2,4
2,5
2,6
2,7
2,8
2,9

Number of operations for i = 2: 8
3,3
3,4
3,5
3,6
3,7
3,8
3,9

Number of operations for i = 3: 7
4,4
4,5
4,6
4,7
4,8
4,9

Number of operations for i = 4: 6
5,5
5,6
5,7
5,8
5,9

Number of operations for i = 5: 5
6,6
6,7
6,8
6,9

Number of operations for i = 6: 4
7,7
7,8
7,9

Number of operations for i = 7: 3
8,8
8,9

Number of operations for i = 8: 2
9,9

Number of operations for i = 9: 1

Number of total operations: 55
```